# Call a procedure(Sub) from a URL?

Tags: vb.net, url

I would like to run a function from a url.

The procedure i would like to run has no parameters and is used to call a stored proc in my database.

Here is what i have tried:

```
> http://localhost:42137/Hlh_shares/RunJobClass/RunJob?
> http://localhost:42137/Hlh_shares/RunJobClass/RunJob
```

---

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data

Public Class RunJobClass
    Public Sub RunJob()
        Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Try

            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn").ConnectionString
            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn

            cmd.CommandText = "[spx_ShareTradingCycles]"
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            conn.Close()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

My Class is located here:
[image]

Comment: It seems like you should are trying to create a webservice. Please do some googling on webservices. You'll probably be able to find a tutorial.

Comment: I don't want a whole web service for one procedure. I don't want to host this web service, i just want to be able to call the one function to run from a link.

Comment: The simplest, make a regular webform and exec the sp inside the page_load event.

Comment: @ajakblackgoat Thanks, i have tried this, i am just struggling to call the URL from WinHost scheduled task's i think it has something to do with my login, so was trying to stay away from a page and rather just call a class procedure.

Comment: Have you tried generic handler?